# PostgreSQL SQL function 10 times slower than hard-coded query

Tags: postgresql

If I hard-code the following function into a query, it gets processed 10 times faster... any ideas on how to make the function run that fast?

I thought that an advantage of writing sql functions was that the query planner was fully functional on such functions, in contrast to PL language functions.

By the way, I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.

---

**UPDATE**

I have now realized that the execution speed difference does not come from putting the query in a function, but rather how I call the function.

`select * from spatial.aggregate_raster_stats_by_geom(155);` >> 1.5 seconds

`select (spatial.aggregate_raster_stats_by_geom(155)).*;` >> 15 seconds

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spatial.aggregate_raster_stats_by_geom(
  IN arg_rid INTEGER
) 
-- This function is called by the trigger that is fired whenever an entry is created in the raster catalog.
RETURNS TABLE(band INTEGER,gid INTEGER, rid INTEGER, product_id INTEGER,ref_datetime TIMESTAMP ,scale INTEGER, count BIGINT, sum FLOAT, mean FLOAT, stddev FLOAT, min FLOAT, max FLOAT) AS
$$
SELECT
    band,
    gid,
    arg_rid as rid,
    product_id,
    ref_datetime,
    scale,
    (ST_SummaryStats(clip,band,TRUE)).* -- compute summary statistics (min and max, etc are also in there). TRUE indicates that nodata should be ignored.
    FROM
      (SELECT
        gid,
        ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast, geom)) as clip -- assemble the raster tiles and clip them with the assembled polygons
      FROM 
        spatial.raster_tiles AS r
      JOIN 
        spatial.geom_catalog AS polygons
        ON ST_Intersects(rast,polygons.geom) -- only select raster tiles that touch the polygons. Spatial indexes should make this fast
      JOIN
        spatial.geom_metadata AS geometa
        ON geometa.product_id = polygons.product_id
      WHERE 
        geometa.aggregate_raster_auto = TRUE
        AND r.rid=$1

      GROUP by gid
      ) as foo
    cross join (
    -- Join bands to the selection
    -- this join has to be introduced AFTER the clipping. If done before, then clipping will be performed for each band.
        SELECT 
          generate_series(md.band_data_start,band_count) as band,
          data_scale_factor as scale,
          md.product_id,
          rid, 
          ref_datetime
        FROM spatial.raster_metadata md 
       JOIN spatial.raster_catalog rst ON rst.product_id = md.product_id
       WHERE rst.rid = $1) AS bar2
$$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: @wildplasser 9.2 and newer should autospecialize plans at parameter bind time, so this issue has mostly gone away. Unless there's some reason it's not being done here.

Comment: @matthew please show `explain (buffers, analyze)` of the stand-alone run. Then try running it via SQL-level `PREPARE` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE`. Is it slow then? If so, post both plans. If it's still fast then, enable the `auto_explain` module, with explain nested statements and analyze mode enabled, and get a plan for the query embedded in the function and post that.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the tip. I did the explains but all of a sudden, the function was just as fast as the stand alone query. Then I realized that I had called the function differently. See the updated question for more detail.

Comment: `select * from spatial.aggregate_raster_stats_by_geom(155);` is the only correct way to call a function that returns a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. You left out the critical details.

In PostgreSQL (at least in 9.5 and older) writing:

```
SELECT ( f () ).*;
```

... runs `f` once for each result column!

It is basically a macro expansion.

To work around it wrap in another layer of subquery.

Comment: The function returns a table - it should be called using `select * from function()` anyway

Comment: Wow. That is really good to know. It also means my `(ST_SummaryStats(clip,band,TRUE)).* ` isn't as efficient as I hoped.

Comment: related link: [http://big-elephants.com/2013-07/table-returning-functions/](http://big-elephants.com/2013-07/table-returning-functions/)